# How to get distinct values from two List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two list.

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
List<string> b = new List<string>();

a.Add("a");
a.Add("b");
a.Add("c");
b.Add("a");
b.Add("c");
```

I want Distinct value into a new list.

Comment: See This Answer this will help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561407/trying-to-get-distinct-values-from-two-listint-objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561407/trying-to-get-distinct-values-from-two-listint-objects)

Comment: The distinct values in your example is just "b", right? Can you edit your question to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 15):

```
a.Concat(b).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just that -

```
var distinct = a.Union(b);
```