# Linq query to remove duplicate rows from two tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have two tables Table_Access1 and Table_Access 2.

```
----------------------------------------
Access_ID | Entity_ID | Entity_LookupID
----------------------------------------
   1      |   4       |  1
----------------------------------------
   2      |   4       |  2
---------------------------------------
   3      |   4       |  10
----------------------------------------  
__________________________________________

----------------------------------------
Access_ID | Entity_ID | Entity_LookupID
----------------------------------------
  0      |   4       |  1
----------------------------------------
   0      |   4       |  2
---------------------------------------
   0     |   4       |  11
---------------------------------------- 
   0     |   4       |  13
---------------------------------------- 

______________________________________
```

Result Table :

```
----------------------------------------
Access_ID | Entity_ID | Entity_LookupID
----------------------------------------
  0      |   4       |  11
----------------------------------------
   0      |   4       |  13
---------------------------------------
```

For `TBL_Access1`, `Access_ID` is Primary Key, `TBL_Access2` is an object from `DTO` with No `Access_ID`. I wanted to insert non-duplicate rows from `Table_Access 2`. The combination of `Entity_ID` and `Entity_LookupID` will be unique. The result table is the output I am looking for.

I am struggling with linq query, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you've attempted.

Comment: Use these solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561407/trying-to-get-distinct-values-from-two-listint-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Worked when I used the below :

```
var userAccessInsert = (from r in TBL_Access2
                                where !(from uA in TBL_Access1
                                       where uA.Entity_LookupID == r.Entity_LookupID
                                       select uA.Entity_LookupID).Contains(r.Entity_LookupID)
                                       select r);
```

Thanks All for your Input.

Comment: This does not look correct. What if LookupID is equal but ID is different?

Comment: In my case, an Access DTO object will never have Entity_ID different. A user is tied to an Implementation(Entity_ID) and it cannot have multiple Implementations with same user.

Comment: I see. This was not obvious from your question. You spoke about a unique *combination* of the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
from t2 in Table_Access2
//join t1 in Table_Access1 on t2.Entity_ID = t1.Entity_ID
from t1 in Table_Access1
where (t2.Entity_ID == t1.Entity_ID && t2.Entity_LookupID != t1.Entity_LookupID)
      || (t2.Entity_LookupID == t1.Entity_LookupID && t2.Entity_ID != t1.Entity_LookupID)
      || (t2.Entity_LookupID != t1.Entity_LookupID && t2.Entity_ID != t1.Entity_LookupID)
      )
select t2
```

Comment: What if Entity_ID is different and Entity_LookupID is the same or when they are both different?

Comment: I wrote the comment before your edit. Your initial code made the join on Entity_ID being equals. This code covers when any of the 2 are equal but not the part when both are different(which also results in a unique combination).

Comment: You can add more OR conditions

Answer (score 0):

This is not linq but, since they are database tables, you could

```
 SELECT * FROM TBL_Access1 LEFT JOIN TBL_Access2 
     ON ( TBL_Access1.Entity_ID <> TBL_Access2.Entity_ID 
          AND TBL_Access1.Entity_LookupID <> TBL_Access2.Entity_LookupID )  
     OR ( TBL_Access1.Entity_ID <> TBL_Access2.Entity_ID 
          AND TBL_Access1.Entity_LookupID = TBL_Access2.Entity_LookupID ) 
     OR ( TBL_Access1.Entity_ID = TBL_Access2.Entity_ID 
          AND TBL_Access1.Entity_LookupID <> TBL_Access2.Entity_LookupID )
```

Answer (score 0):

using not any should work for what you need. although your request seems like you would want the 3rd record from table1.

```
var query = TBL_Access2
            .Where(t2 => !TBL_Access1
            .Any(t1 => t1.Entity_ID == t2.Entity_ID && t1.Entity_LookupID == t1.Entity_LookupID));
```